# JetBrains Toolbox recent project not updated

Tags: jetbrains-toolbox

I'm using the JetBrains Toolbox App. I do not see that the recent projects tab is updated.

I open PyCharm everyday but it only shows project opened 1 week ago! But if I open PyCharm, it can show recent projects correctly.

How can I solve this problem? Where does Toolbox search for recent projects?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same problem as well.

The recent projects for IntelliJ are stored under:

- mac: `~/Library/Preferences/IntelliJIdea2018.3/options/recentProjects.xml`
- linux: `~/.IntelliJIdea2018.3/config/options/recentProjects.xml`

The recent projects for CLion they are stored under:

- mac: `~/Library/Preferences/CLion2018.3/options/recentProjectDirectories.xml`
- linux: `~/.CLion2018.3/config/options/recentProjectDirectories.xml`

After looking at the xml in the `recentProjects.xml` file, I noticed that only one of the projects from the xml list options was actually shown in the Toolbox App project tab. The reason in my case was because I had set a custom path variable in the IntelliJ settings under `Appearance & Behavior -> Path Variable` to point to my desktop directory.

The xml for the one project that actually appeared in the Toolbox App was listed as `<option value="$USER_HOME$/path/to/project" />`. All my other recently opened projects that were not showing up in the Toolbox projects tab were listed as `<option value="$desktop$/path/to/file" />`.

After removing the desktop variable in IntelliJ's Path Variable settings window all my recent projects showed up in the Toolbox App.

So not sure if you have added any path variables but if you have that is probably what is causing the problem. Either way I would recommend looking at the `recentProjects.xml` or `recentProjectDirectories.xml` file. Not sure which one PyCharm uses.